# User Authentication in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have a question about the built in user authentication functionality in laravel. 
I got the authentication part to work but it doesn't seem like a user is stored in the session.

```
Route::get('login', function(){
    $username = 'stardriver'; 
    $password = '1234'; 


    $creds = array('username' => $username, 'password' => $password);
    if(Auth::attempt($creds)){ //I assume that its already logged in when it goes here

        return Auth::guest(); //but why does this return 1?
    }else{
        return 'nope wrong creds'; //if I change the username or password declared above, it goes here
    }


});
```

Here's my admin page. I get an infinite loop when I redirect to this page after the user has successfully authenticated.

```
Route::get('admin', array('before' => 'auth', 'do' => function(){

    return "you are logged in! " . HTML::link('logout', 'logout dude');
}));
```

What do you think is wrong here?

Comment: Stupid question but do you have all that setup in your database ?

Comment: yes I've set it up. There's no way I'll get inside the Auth::attempt($creds) if I haven't set it up.

Comment: Alright do me a favor, and return Auth::check(); instead of Auth::guest(), just to see what that returns

Comment: Auth::check() it returns nothing

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Dayle Rees said on its blog :

> Please remember not to apply the auth filter to your login URI, you
>   will experience a terrible loop!

Follow this tutorial, and everything should be sweet :)
http://daylerees.com/2012/04/07/laravel-authentication/

Comment: link is down. any mirror?